# How to set session variable

Tags: magento2, session, variables

I need to set a variable session in Magento, do I do just procedural PHP or is there a proper way in Magento 2 ?

Example :

```
$_SESSION['myKey'] = "00001";
```

@AnsarHunsain code help me, but I can't get my value into another page. My page and my block are on the same module than the block where I've defined getCheckoutSession.

I have this error with this :

```
  echo $block->getCheckoutSession()->getCommande();
```

> Call to a member function getCommande() on null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use to set and get custom session value like below

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

    $catalogSession = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session');
    //customerSession  \Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
    //checkoutSession = \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

    // set session variables and their value
    $catalogSession->setMyName('Test');


    // print session variables value
    echo $catalogSession->getMyName(); // Test


    // Unset session
    $catalogSession->unsMyName();
```

You can use dependency injection also like below

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Session extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_catalogSession;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCatalogSession() 
    {
        return $this->_catalogSession;
    }  
}
?>
```

Use below code in phtml file

```
$block->getCatalogSession()->setMyName('Test');
echo $block->getCatalogSession()->getMyName(); // Test
```

Comment: isn't Object manager to avoid ?  And can I replace "setMyName" by "setAnythingElse" ?

Comment: yes you can use dependency injection at the place of object manager and yes you can use setAnythingElse

Comment: Ok thanks, I think it's gonna be ok, I have I any trouble I'll come back

Comment: Should I do this in controller or in a block php file ?

Comment: if you want to display this session value in phtml file then do it in block specially other wise you can use it anywhere

Comment: I want to display it but I don't see how to do. Should I put each one of these in method ?

Comment: I have updated code in post check now with dependency

Comment: Ok, this seems to work. So when I need to access this value, I need to inject my block and then getCatalogSession ?

Comment: yes you can use

Comment: In my second page, this :      echo $block->getCheckoutSession()->getCommande();
 is giving me white page :/

Comment: uncomment app/bootstrap.php this line ini_set('display_errors', 1) and see what is error ?

Comment: Call to a member function getMyName() on null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83368/discussion-between-ansar-husain-and-morgan-tartreau).